# Can I mass delete e-mail using Exchange Management Shell?

Tags: exchange-2013

Is it possible to mass delete e-mail using Exchange Management Shell?

I understand that this would never be suggested for obvious reasons, but I am curious as to whether it can be done.

For example if I wanted to delete all e-mail in all folders for all users that was sent or received prior to January 1, 2014, could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided you have the correct permissions on each mailbox this can be done.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/10/27/removing-specific-messages-from-your-exchange-server.aspx